# How i should use date filter in where clause in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, express

**user input**

```
{
        "user_id": 1,
        "schedeuled_time": "22-03-2020"
    }
```

IN DATABASE DATE IS STORED IN DATETIME FORMAT 
for eg:- `2020-03-22 15:30:00`

How can I exactly filter using one date because the below followed method is not suitable.

```
 `SELECT
                        todo_id,
                        todo_item,
                        user_id,
                        DATE_FORMAT(schedeuled_time, '%d-%m-%Y') as 
                        schedeuled_date,
                        DATE_FORMAT(schedeuled_time, '%l:%i% %p') as 
                        schedeuled_time,
                        is_done,
                        is_time_passed
                     FROM to_do_table 
                     WHERE is_deleted = 0 AND
                     user_id = ${req.body.user_id} AND
                     schedeuled_time LIKE ('%${req.body.schedeuled_time}%')
                     order by schedeuled_time`
```

I WANT TO USE ONLY ONE DATE 
For eg:- `WHERE scheduled_time = '26-03-2020'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to get just the date part of the datetime and [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to get the valid date value of the user input:

```
SELECT
  todo_id,
  todo_item,
  user_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(schedeuled_time, '%d-%m-%Y') AS schedeuled_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(schedeuled_time, '%l:%i% %p') AS schedeuled_time,
  is_done,
  is_time_passed
FROM to_do_table 
WHERE is_deleted = 0 
  AND user_id = ${req.body.user_id}
  AND DATE(schedeuled_time) = STR_TO_DATE('${req.body.schedeuled_time}', '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY schedeuled_time
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you use a *query parameter,* and simply provide a date or a string `YYYY-MM-DD` as that parameter.  (Many back-ends, given a Date-type variable, will simply do it for you.)